# Are 4755 permissions safe for usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users, d-bus

I somehow messed up the permissions of many files on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS system (privately used computer, not a server), which has already caused a couple of problems. Recently, I noticed that I couldn't start `Users and Groups` via the GUI.

It resulted in the error message:

`The configuration could not be loaded. An unknown error occurred.`

By investigating a bit I found out that the program runs again when I change the permissions of `/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` from `-rwsr-xr--` (4744) to `-rwsr-xr-x` (4755).

I used `ls -l /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` for investigating the permissions and `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` changing the permissions.

Is this safe? If not, what are my alternatives to make the programme run again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are tools which can be expected to have improved privileges to help users or user's processes to use a feature without having the privilege to do it directly. So it's not surprising that giving back privileges restores their functionality.

However. Some privileges don't require root (and thus setuid root) to be achieved: [capabilities](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/capabilities.7.html), which are subsets of what can a full root user do are sometimes enough but their flags on a file are deleted when ownership is changed. Some privileges on helpers are reserved to only a limited subset of users or processes by access rights.

The later is the case for `/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`.

The [postinst script of `dbus`](https://salsa.debian.org/utopia-team/dbus/-/blob/debian/bookworm/debian/dbus.postinst#L28) (which provides this file) changes its permissions and ownership like this:

> ```
> MESSAGEUSER=messagebus
> ```

> ```
> LAUNCHER=/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
> ```

(the user/group is also created if not existing)

> ```
> dpkg-statoverride --update --add root "$MESSAGEUSER" 4754 "$LAUNCHER"
> ```

restricting its use to processes having the group `messagebus` rather than to any processes like in current OP's case.

So since the system is functional, the easiest is to reinstall the `dbus` package so it fixes the permissions:

```
apt-get reinstall dbus
```

or else manually:

```
chown root:messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
chmod 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

You might have to check all the other affected files, especially if there are helper tools involved.

---

Additional notes about the package's `postinst` metadata file:

- to find which package:

  ```
  dpkg -S /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
  ```

  which should answer:

  ```
  dbus: /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
  ```
- where are the package's metadata?

  For package FOO, until now they have always been located in various `/var/lib/dpkg/info/FOO.*` files (for multi-arch packages (usually libraries) they might also include `:amd64` or any othe architecture too to give `/var/lib/dpkg/info/FOO:amd64.*`).

  The `postinst` script to check is thus:

  ```
  /var/lib/dpkg/info/dbus.postinst
  ```
- without having the package installed:

  ```
  cd /tmp
  apt-get download dbus
  dpkg --raw-extract dbus_*.deb /tmp/somewhere

  less /tmp/somewhere/DEBIAN/postinst
  ```

This kind of file is often auto-generated, but for `dbus` it's provided in sources. Here's a link to the file for the Debian repository (it even includes a few older Ubuntu tags, anyway it's about the same content): [`debian/dbus.postinst`](https://salsa.debian.org/utopia-team/dbus/-/blob/debian/bookworm/debian/dbus.postinst#L28)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now everything works well. I had actually already reinstalled the package before, so maybe setting the chmod +x was unnecessary in the first place. For my better understanding of this issue: Where can I find the postinst script of dbus?

Comment: @LololoTheGreat added it in the answer (including an URL linked twice)